# Replace or update a line in bash script

Tags: bash, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a `test.tf` file  content of file is something like this

```
variable "google_account_key" { default = "none" }
variable "aws_ec2_key" { default = "none" }
variable "golang_key" { default = "none" }
```

Now when I get input from user I want to update that file **FOR EXAMPLE**

```
read -s -p "--> Kindly enter Name for ec2 key: " name
```

Now what ever user will enter I will replace default to **aws_ec2_key** in `test.tf`  file.

Comment: Please: sample data for testing, related output and work done, all in text, edited to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: @JamesBrown  what ? I didn't get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to replace an occurrence of a word in a file, you're looking for a `sed` command with `-i` flag to actually save the replacement in-file. We cannot replace the word `"none"` since that would replace all of them, so we should look for `"aws_ec2_key" { default = "none"` and replace this `"none"` with user input. See [this discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66878/how-can-i-replace-text-after-a-specific-word-using-sed) for more info :)

You're looking for something along the lines of:

```
read -s -p "--> Kindly enter Name for ec2 key: " name
sed -i "s/\"aws_ec2_key\" { default = \"none\" }/\"aws_ec2_key\" { default = \"$name\" }/g" test.tf
```

- Note that we're using double quotes `"` rather than the usual single `'` so we can use a bash variable `$name` in the sed-command.
- If you're on mac, the `sed` command [works slightly different](https://mkyong.com/mac/sed-command-hits-undefined-label-error-on-mac-os-x/). The `-i` flag requires an additional parameter to tell what kind of backup to use, for instance replace `sed -i` by `sed -i 'bak'`.

Comment: not working . things remain unchanged